# jQuery selector not working the way I'm expecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider the following simple HTML:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
        <a href="#"><img alt="" src="Img1.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img alt="" src="Img2.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img alt="" src="Img3.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img alt="" src="Img4.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img alt="" src="Img5.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

And for the sake of argument, let's say it's a very small portion of a large page with many DIV's and A's.

What I want to do is hide the  tags and the images inside them. If I do this, it works:

```
$('a').hide();
```

But like I said, there are a lot of links on the page, so I want to be very specific. Essentially, I want ONLY the links that are inside a `<div>` with the class of "navcontainer". So from what I'm seeing on the web, it should be one of the following two formats. The second one looks perfect to me. But neither is working for me.

```
$('div.navcontainer a').hide();
$('div.navcontainer > a').hide();
```

I must be missing something stupid. Can anyone please clue me in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mixed up the class and Id selector

```
$('#navcontainer a').hide();
$('#navcontainer > a').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

A dot prefix in a selector is for *classes*, but you've actually got an ID so you should use a hash prefix instead, e.g:

```
$('#navcontainer > a').hide();
```

It's far better *not* to put the `div` prefix on the selector - it'll be much faster without it.

If you use a pure ID-based selector then jQuery can use the native `document.getElementById()` call.  In practise this is probably the most optimal:

```
$('#navcontainer').children('a').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div#navcontainer a').hide();
```

`.` is for classes, you want `#` for IDs.

Since IDs are (should be) unique, you don't need the `div` prefix.

```
$('#navcontainer a').hide();
```

Comment: Not a bad practice, though, to specify DIV. In jQuery, it never hurts to be more specific, especially if someone else is reading your code.

Comment: @KyleMacey yes, it does hurt to be more specific, it slows down the code.

Comment: Yes, there is a performance issue, specifying DIV does loop through all divs... My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need `$('div#navcontainer')`, your code is looking for navcontainer class rather than id.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the div with class navcontainer, use

```
 $(".navcontainer a").hide()
```

if you have a div with id navcontainer. use

```
 $("#navcontainer a").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your html, you need to use the id selector -

```
$('div#navcontainer > a').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#navcontainer a').hide();
$('div#navcontainer > a').hide();
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of your code so that it may be better understood. You may click the 'edit' link that is right above this comment to do so.